# Django Migration Missing ManyToManyField

Tags: django, django-models

I've added a ManyToManyField to my app. Every restaurant can fall under many categories, and each category can be applied to many restaurants. The app has been working and running, and my models look like this:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "categories"

    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

class RestaurantInfo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    aboutUs = models.TextField(max_length=10000)
    founded = models.DateField()

    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

The ManyToManyFied is what is new. However, make migrations finds no changes to make.

Comment: Where exactly are you looking, and what are you expecting to show up that isn't?

Comment: I am looking in my database. I would expect that a link between the tables would be created. I'm not seeing one.

Comment: Can you show the relevant migration file?

Comment: It finds no migrations to apply.

Comment: Sorry, now I'm confused about the order of events. You added the `categories` field, then did you run `manage.py makemigrations`? Was a migration file created?

Comment: I ran makemigrations and got No changes found, I'm sorry if it wasn't clear.

Comment: What version of Django are you running? `makemigrations` has only been implemented since [1.7](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/migrations/#a-brief-history)

Comment: What does `manage.py validate` give you?

Comment: System check identified no issues (0 silenced)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are not supplying `app_name` to `makemigrations` command.

```
python manage.py makemigrations app_name
```

If you won't supply `app_name`, Django won't detect changes made to your models.

Comment: Just checked that - I ran makemigrations through pycharm, which provides the app name to the command

Comment: Not sure why that is happening then. Try adding a dummy model & check if it detects changes.